# Counting the number of occurances of text in a range and summarize in a list

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I'd like to use a formula to inspect a range of text values in a Google Sheet, and summarize the number of occurrences found for each unique value.

[image: Example range of text values and generated summary]

Answer (score 1):

use:

```
=INDEX(QUERY(FLATTEN(A:C); 
 "select Col1,count(Col1) 
  where Col1 is not null 
  group by Col1 
  label count(Col1)''"))
```